# es posible agregar un if en un $("#matriz tbody").append(markup);

Tags: jquery, laravel, condiciones

Lo que quiero es meter un if dentro de un append, preguntar si el dato que viene vale 1 entonces escribir cerrado y si no pues activo

sera posible

//Parte de mi codigo

Alguien me podria ayudar ```
//****  Cargar información empresas registradas ****//

```
                        var infodetalle = response.data.empresas_registradas;
                        
                        for (var i = 0; i < infodetalle.length; i++) {

                        var markup = "<tr id='"+infodetalle[i].id+"'>"+

                             "<td align='center'>"+                
                                  "<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'onclick=VerEmpresa('"+infodetalle[i].id+"')>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fas fa-search'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>"+
                            "</td>"+

                            "<td align='center'>"+
                                infodetalle[i].nombre+
                            "</td>"+                      

                            "<td align='center'>"+
                                infodetalle[i].nombre_giro+
                            "</td>"+

                            "<td align='center'>"+
                            (!infodetalle[i].estado==1? '': '<span class="badge badge-danger">Cerrado</span>') +
                            (!infodetalle[i].estado==2? '': '<span class="badge badge-success">Activo</span>') +
                            "</td>"+

                            "<td align='center'>"+
                            "<span class='badge badge-pill badge-dark'> "+infodetalle[i].num_tarjeta+" </span>"+
                            "</td>"+

                            "</tr>";

                        $("#matriz_ver_empresas tbody").append(markup);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es posible, debes ocupar [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (una comilla simple invertida)

```
var infodetalle = response.data.empresas_registradas;
                        
for (var i = 0; i < infodetalle.length; i++) {

    var markup = `<tr id="${infodetalle[i].id}">
    <td align="center">               
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="VerEmpresa('${infodetalle[i].id}')>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-search"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
    </td>

    <td align="center">
        ${infodetalle[i].nombre}
    </td>                     

    <td align='center'>
        ${infodetalle[i].nombre_giro}
    </td>

    <td align="center">
    ${infodetalle[i].estado == 1 ? '<span class="badge badge-success">Activo</span>' : '<span class="badge badge-danger">Cerrado</span>'}
    </td>

    <td align="center">
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-dark">${infodetalle[i].num_tarjeta}</span>
    </td>

</tr>`;
$("#matriz_ver_empresas").append(markup);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta sin embargo no me funciono, quizá algo aun sigue estando mal

Comment: Había una comilla de sobra, prueba ahora

Comment: Si ahora si se pudo. Te agradezco demnasiado.